# can't change password on Mac Help!

Tags: macos

I am trying to change the password of a user on my MacBook Air.  from the apple dropdown menu, I go to System Pref then User/Groups and I can log in to my user but the bar to "Change Password" does not highlight/will not allow me to change the password.

Where do I go to change whatever preference is not allowing me to change the password?

Comment: did you click the lock icon (lower left) and authenticate?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the user preferences pane.

Comment: A screen shot or Apple support might be a good place to start [if this link isn’t enough](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/301421/5472) to get some better answers. Are you sure your account is an administrator?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the privileges to do that? Your account might not be able to change the password. This can be the case if it's company provided laptop with a company provided account for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn’t mention which macOS you use, here is the latest step by step process.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-the-login-password-on-mac-mchlp1550/mac

If you’re not an administrator, that locks your ability to change other accounts

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-users-groups-user-preferences-mh11774/mac

If you have a backup, now is a great time to check it and maybe perform one new backup just in case the cause of this is error instead of a process or someone locking down that Mac.