# How to get (my father's) Macbook Password

Tags: macbook-pro, password, hacking

I first want to apologize if this is not allowed, I am super new to this website and I am desperate for information.

As the title says I am wanting to find out my late father's Macbook password. He had passed several months ago and I am just now going through some of his belongings with help from my mother. We finally got to his Macbook and realized that my mother does not know the password and neither do I. I know you can easily reset the password but for memories' sake (and curiosity's), I would like to find out the password and maybe keep it as I will be taking the computer since my mother has no use for it).

I have obviously Googled how to get the Macbook's password but I cannot find anything that is simple/clear or something that still works with the newest update (I would like to think my father kept it updated, but I am uncertain).
If you have any suggestions on any free programs, methods, videos, guides, etc., it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115939/how-to-recover-from-a-forgotten-password-for-macbook-pro

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover from a forgotten password for MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115939/how-to-recover-from-a-forgotten-password-for-macbook-pro)

Comment: From the question: "I know you can easily reset the password but for memories' sake (and curiosity's), I would like to find out the password", so this is not about getting access but about recovering the password itself.

Comment: Depending on which macOS - then here is another thread: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220729/what-type-of-hash-are-a-macs-password-stored-in - but you still need to create a new local user, which was described how to do in the other thread.

Comment: My answer (or better hints) linked in Rene's comment won't work anymore (in 10.15) because *defaults* truncates the ShadowHashData part of the plist. It works succesfully up to 10.13 though. I haven't tested it in 10.14.

Comment: @Mint_Rebecca I need the file  /private/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/⁠
**username**.plist from the **system volume** (10.14 and less e.g. *Macintosh HD*) or from the **system data volume** (10.15 e.g. *Macintosh HD - Data*) to crack the password. **username** is your father's short user name.

Comment: @nohillside Yes, I'm wanting to recover the password. I mean if it comes down to it I'm fine not having it.

Comment: @klanomath I wouldn't have a clue how to do that. Do you have a link to a video on how I could do that? Sorry I'm not too tech savvy I guess

Comment: @Mint_Rebecca 1. You have to boot the Mac to Recovery Mode (pressing the keys *command* **and** *R* while starting the Mac)

Comment: @Mint_Rebecca 2. Then (after booting has finished) you have to open Terminal (menubar > Utilities > Terminal) and type `diskutil list` and (to execute this command) hit the enter key. You'll get a long sorted list of devices. The important device is the internal disk of the MacBook. Usually it's at the top and its device node is disk0. I need the number of subdevices of  disk0 and their names (e.g. disk0s1 EFI, disk0s2 Macintosh HD, disk0s3 Recovery HD).

Comment: @klanomath Sorry for such a late reply, I've been busy with Corona (nurse). Is there any videos or walkthroughs so I could do it myself and not bother you so much? Thank you!